# Regex C# missing text

Tags: c#, regex

I use the code above, but the results returned are missing. Although, when I used it on regex101.com, regexr.com and RegexBuddy, it works correctly.
it is missing text:

> - "[6]Thái Thượng Lão Quân (太上老君) là tôn hiệu một vị thần tiên tối cao trong Đạo giáo Trung Quốc, một trong Tam Thanh. Cõi của Thái Thượng
>     Lão Quân ngự gọi là Thanh Cảnh."
> - "Chương ba: Mới nhập phàm trần đã gặp xui xẻo, làm trò cười cho thiên hạ! ...[7] Nam Thiên Môn là giao giới giữa trời và người."

```
public static string ReadHTMLCode(string URL)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] reqHTML;
        reqHTML = webClient.DownloadData(URL);
        UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        return objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML);

    }//method read HTMLcode


public static string get_story_ttv(string url)
    {
        string source = Class_test.ReadHTMLCode(url);
        string pattern = @"[\w \”\.ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐÐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹếý\n\,\“\]\[\(\)\!\…\?\:\-\—\–]+(?=<br \/>\n<br \/>)|^[\w \”\.ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐÐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹếý\n\,\“\]\[\(\)\!\…\?\:\-\—\–]+$";
        Match m = Regex.Match(source, pattern);
        string S_rt = "";
        int kt = 0;
        while (m.Success)
        {
            S_rt += m.Groups[0].Value.Trim() + "\r\n";
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        return S_rt;
    }//method get text regex


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://www.tangthuvien.vn/forum/showthread.php?t=94781";
        richTextBox1.Text = Class_test.get_story_ttv(url);
        MessageBox.Show("DONE");
    }//event buttonClick
```

Comment: I suggest you check [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It is very easy to parse HTML with it.

Comment: Is this a real question or are you trolling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thank you! But I want to know why it is not working properly.

Comment: When testing regular expressions make sure to use a site that supports .Net like http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: You'll have to forgive but, I don't want to download some HTML from a Vietnamese URL and and attempt to test your overly complex regular expression against it. Especially when I already know that using a regular expression to parse arbitrary HTML is a bad idea. Use HtmlAgilityPack, to get the text before you consider using a Regex, as @WiktorStribiżew suggests.

Comment: link regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oE9eO5/1

Comment: I will try and report back later. thank you!